# Jquery code conflicting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm using a load bar before the page loads and i m using mix-it-up plug in but when i put load bar code its just stops working

my load bar js

```
// <===============load===================>


$(function() {
 $('.content-body').hide();
 $(".preload").fadeOut(2000, function() {
  $(".content-body").fadeIn(1000);       
 });
});
```

my html

```
<div class="preload"><img src="img/hex.gif"></div>
<div class="content-body">
<!--content-->
</div>
```

you can see http://jsfiddle.net/uQTb2/1/ for convienence what i'm talking about

my mix it up code

```
$(function() {
 $('.mixitup').mixItUp();
});
```

now i don't know what's the problem here when i remove the load bar code , mix-it-up starts working

Answer (score 1):

Its working fine in demo which i created.

Check out [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uQTb2/469/)

```
$(function () {
    $(".preload").fadeOut(2000, function () {
        $(".content").fadeIn(1000);
    });

    $('.mixitup').mixItUp();
});
```

Comment: yeah its working but when i put      $('.content').hide(); before the page loads mix it up stop mixing things up

Comment: @danialpervaiz can u able to put full html and js code or if you can create fiddle and send me link then i will be happy to help.

Comment: may b u can understand i put the link